# How to create a calculus derivative solver using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, calculus

I've been trying to create my own JavaScript program for solving problems in Calculus such as taking the derivative of an equation, but as of yet have not succeeded.  I would be greatly appreciative if someone could help me with this.

Comment: what kind of functions do you want to take derivative of ? There is no general formula for taking a derivative of a function

Comment: Make sure you mention specifically what you are struggling with.

Comment: Just a simple function, such as a^3 + b^2 +c.

Comment: But if you want to calculate approximatively a derivative, that's possible using derivative formula approximation (at point x) (f(x+h)-f(x))/h, taking h as small as you want

Comment: i'm just wanting to make a program for it using Javascript.  I know how to do it manually. I got 1st place in a state competition for Related Technical Math.

Comment: So this derivative is trivial, you can fix for an nth degree polynomial some basic method. Btw I found this link (http://code.google.com/p/smath/wiki/smathJavaScriptAPI)

Comment: @Newben, a lot of [math libraries](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html) do this.  Some use sampling based approaches which are often used to take approximate derivatives, and some operate on symbolic forms.

Comment: Umm... Can you try to give me a watered- down version of this website? I'm not even through my first Javascript programming class yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that should do it

```
function poly(variable, degree){
 return degree*((variable)^(degree-1));
}
```

You shoud store your polynomial of degree n in an (n+1) 'array' and using Jquery each method

```
var result = 0;
$.each(array, function(index, value) {
  result = result + poly(value,index);
});
```

Edit : if you don't know about jquery, you can use pure javascript for loop, `for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {...}`

Comment: Thank you Newben, i really appreciate it.

Comment: If you found it usefull, you can upvote and vallidate the answer :)

Comment: i validated the answer, but how to validate? First time using this site...

Comment: it is Ok now you have validated, and to upvote, you press the up arrow. You can't upvote twice (and there is a few minutes to wait after posting a question to be able to validate)

Comment: Have to have 15 reputation first, sorry...